# How to Select Dropdown which does not have a Name or ID in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I can't select the dropdown which has no attribute associated with it. Below HTML code, can see there is a select tag but no id or name with it. How do I select that tag in Selenium?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the website where that dropdown is located.
Website: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

I have tried from the root of the document, following-sibling, etc., but nothing worked out. 
I get **NOSUCHELEMENT EXCEPTION**

That is the reason, I am posting a question here.

Following is my code,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class X 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");
        WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/select"));
        Select s = new Select(element);
        s.selectByValue("saab");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to switch to the `iframe` first and after to find the element.

Comment: First come to frame and then go to select and 'S' should be capital in "Saab"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here the problem is, your element is in `iFrame` So first you need to find correct `iFrame` i.e  with the name `iframeResult` in your page and switch into it.

Then you can locate same dropdown with tagname itself:
Use following code and let me know if there any issue

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
Select select = new Select(element);
select.selectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, click on your element to expand dropdown:
`s.click()`

Next try one of methods below:

- `s.selectByValue("saab")`
- `s.selectByVisibleText("saab")`
- `s.selectByIndex(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys. Please upvote my question if found useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is half correct, first of all you have to switch to frame and then try to select value from drop down . Your correct code should be like this:

```
public class X 
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
        WebElement dropdownBrands = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/select"));
        Select s = new Select(dropdownBrands);
        s.selectByVisibleText("Saab");

    }
}
```